# Is it grammatical to reduce relative clauses in past tense

Tags: grammar, relative-clauses

"The shares of Americans **going to** restaurants every day and **not going at all** both stayed at below 5% in 2013 after declining marginally between 2003 and 2006."

"From 2003 to 2006, the proportions of Americans **visiting restaurants once a week, several times a week, and a few times a year** increased slightly from about 31 to 33%, 17 to 20%, and 13 to 15%, respectively."

I reduced "the proportions of Americans who visited restaurants once a week, many times a week, and a few times a year..." to the above sentence.

I have checked several online websites yet haven't still found rules on how to reduce relative clauses. A constant piece of advice I always see is that not all relative clauses should be reduced. And I don't know whether the relative clause in my sentence above is one of those clauses that shouldn't be reduced.

Please, give me tips, and send links to websites that provide detailed explanations on how to reduce relative clauses.

Comment: Those are both fine. I have no idea what restrictions there are one such clauses.

Comment: They are not relative clauses at all, reduced or otherwise. They have the same meanings as the corresponding relative clauses, and they are modifiers, but they are actually gerund-participial (_ing_) clauses.